# does not align at left

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\int3x^2dx\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^4}\\
&\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\
&\int5a^3 da\\
&\int \frac{dt}{t^3}\\
&\int x^2t^3dx\\
&\int x^2t^3dt\\
&\int x^2t^3dy\\
&\int da
\end{alignat}
```

When I run this code, integrals get aligned at the middle but I want to be aligned at left. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add the `fleqn` option  to your document class (equations or groups thereof will be aligned at the left margin), or, if it is only for specific equations, nest them in the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`.

*Unrelated*: why do you use `alignat{2}` and a single alignment point?